# How do I control the spacing of the bottom border?

Tags: html, css

I want to accomplish two thing here:

1) I'd like to control the spacing of the bottom border. Is there any way to have the bottom border show up 5 pixels down below the type?
2) Also, I would like the word "Enhance" in bold. So the first word in my example should be bold.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9zLj27j/6/

Here's my code:

```css
h1 {
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size:1.6em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:normal;
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}
h1.section-title {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size:32px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 50px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;
}
h1.section-title-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.rtecenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.blue {
  color: #2251a4;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="section-title rtecenter blue">
<span class="section-title-bold">Enhance</span> Your Search</h1>
```

Comment: is this what you are [looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/m9zLj27j/9/) ?

Comment: Maddy got it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it,

1) You can control the spacing using padding.
2) and for bold you done well but make a space between the class `h1 .section-title-bold`

```css
h1 {
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size:1.6em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:normal;
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}
h1.section-title {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size:32px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 50px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
h1 .section-title-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.rtecenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.blue { 
  color: #2251a4;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="section-title rtecenter blue">
  <span class="section-title-bold">Enhance</span> Your Search
</h1>
```

**[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/m9zLj27j/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may try this updates:

```
h1.section-title {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 50px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;
    padding-bottom: 5px; /* bottom spacing */
}

span.section-title-bold { /* used span instead of h1 */
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hz5ys4sa/)

**HTML**

```
    <h1 class="section-title rtecenter blue">
    <span class="section-title-bold">Enhance</span> Your Search</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:1.6em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}

    h1.section-title {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
        font-size:32px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 50px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;
         padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

h1 .section-title-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.rtecenter {
text-align: center;
}

.blue { color: #2251a4; }
```

Answer (score 0):

to make "Enhance" bold just simply add strong tags around it like this:
`<strong>Enhance</strong>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems `h1` already bolds the inside text. So, you better use a `div` instead of `h1` or use high font-size for "Enhance" text.

Coming to `5px` gap to the border, you can do that using `:after` pseudo class.

**CSS**

```
.section-title {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:32px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin: 50px 0;
}
.section-title:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
section-title-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}
.blue {
    color: #2251a4;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9zLj27j/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:1.6em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding-bottom:5px;}

    h1.section-title {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
        font-size:32px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 50px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;}

h1.section-title-bold {
    font-weight: 600;}

.rtecenter {
text-align: center;
}

.blue { color: #2251a4; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [Click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9zLj27j/12/)

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="section-title rtecenter blue">
    <strong class="section-title-bold">Enhance</strong> Your Search</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1.section-title {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 50px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #f66511;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
}
```